# IIS high process load

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cpu

I have an IIS server version 8.5. I have web site and a number of web-services hosted on this web site. A number of windows services and desktop apps are working this with IIS instance. And everything is ok for some time. But some time later IIS begin to use 100% of cpu resources. I can suppose that my code is the probem, but firstly i'm doing next steps:

1. I'm switching off all windows services and desktop apps.
2. Switching off w3wp process from processes.
3. Restrating several times app pool, iis and site.

But after i'm startig again iis, pool and site and nothing else (nothing is using iis) i can see that iis worker process using about 20% of cpu resources. And the situation above can be repeated again after some time.  It means that the problem can't be in the my code.

What can be the problem of the iis high-load then it just started and then it uses 100% of cpu?

Comment: You're saying `w3wp.exe` is showing the high resource usage? Then it's probably your application. You may be spinning up threads or having memory leaks or any other number of problems.

Comment: "It means that the problem can't be in the my code" is almost certainly an incorrect assumption.

Comment: but how can you explain that when all clients of web services are not working iis is showing the high resource usage? iis contains just five web services and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens, we've all struggled with high CPU in a worker process before. It in almost all cases it is the code.

If you're threading (That's probably your answer right their)

But here's what you need to do.

Right click on the process consuming the CPU and click "Dump Process", this will create a debug file.

Then use [debug diagnostic tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) from Microsoft and open the file, it has a wealth of information in it. It's your starting point. Unless you're willing to share the code.

Comment: Thank's, i will try it when this will happen again.

Comment: Just an update, the link above doesn't work anymore. The tool is currently at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210